# Why is there a ConnectionString not initialized error

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

Content page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string gs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ging"].ConnectionString;
    if (Master.showCheck(s))
    {
        //do something...
    }
}
```

MasterPage:

```
string gs = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ging"].ConnectionString;
}
public bool showCheck(string strID)
{
    string strCheckIfParentExist = @"";

    using (SqlConnection scConn = new SqlConnection(gs))
    {
        scConn.Open(); //throws an error: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized'
    }
}
```

Why do I receive the following error: `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized`

Comment: I suspect because your connection string is empty, so `gs` has no value. Some debugging would be able to check that.

Comment: I have the `gs` set in the page load for the MasterPage. Do I need to add another one inside the `showCheck()` function?

Comment: do you have the ConnectionStrings tag setted in web.config file?

Comment: What does the connection look like in your `web.config`?

Comment: `<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ging" connectionString="User ID=myid1; Password=mypass1; Data Source=svr123; Initial Catalog=polt;" />
</connectionStrings>`

Comment: It works fine in the page itself but when calling from the content page into the master page is when it shows the error.

Comment: Shouldn't that "gs" be a class member not a local variable? the code as posted does not seem to be compilable.

Comment: @IsmailHawayel Sorry I forgot to fix it.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge then in the content page, remove "string" from in front of it, cause that is now shadowing the class member and the class member is not getting initialized.

Comment: So the `gs` coming over from content page and not taking the MasterPage?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string gs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ging"].ConnectionString;
}
public bool showCheck(string strID)
{
    string strCheckIfParentExist = @"";

    using (SqlConnection scConn = new SqlConnection(gs))
    {
        scConn.Open(); //throws an error: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized'
    }
}
```

To

```
private string gs = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ging"].ConnectionString;
}
public bool showCheck(string strID)
{
    string strCheckIfParentExist = @"";

    using (SqlConnection scConn = new SqlConnection(gs))
    {
        scConn.Open(); //throws an error: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized'
    }
}
```

Basically your variable is getting declared in a different method from where you're calling it, so you just need to increase it's scope to the class.

Comment: If he is really going to go that route, he should declare it as a `private readonly` that he can inject throughout the page life cycle.

Comment: I have it as string `gs = "";` as a global variable.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge You should do: `private readonly string dbConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["..."].ConnectionString;`  Then you can simply utilize `dbConnection`.  Also, I recommend not storing a `connection` for a master page.

Comment: Greg agreed, that's how I typically do it.  SearchForKnowledge then why are you declaring it again in your page load? + that wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

If you have "gs" as a class member, change the content page to

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ging"].ConnectionString;
    if (Master.showCheck(s))
    {
        //do something...
    }
}
```

string def you have there is shadowing the class member.